# Will renaming a MySQL table to another database result in a full table copy operation on disk?

Tags: mysql, rename

I understand that renaming a table within the same database will not generally result in a table copy... It's not clear to me if this holds true for renaming across databases.

For reference, I want to move/rename a ~1TB table to a different database, and I don't want to initiate a huge copy operation.

Will renaming a MySQL table to another database result in a full table copy operation on disk? Please provide an explanation or references if possible.

Comment: Rename table and move table are two different operations without any relation between. You may, of course,  create new table using LIKE, discard both table's tablespaces, swap files in the filesystem then import tablespaces. Do not forget - all FKs to and from the source table must be removed before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends entirely on the disk volume of the source database and the target database.

Given the mysqld instance uses `/var/lib/mysql` as datadir and you run

```
ALTER TABLE mydb1.mytb RENAME mydb2.mytb;
```

OR

```
RENAME TABLE mydb1.mytb TO mydb2.mytb;
```

Here is what happens under the hood

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/mydb1/mytb.frm /var/lib/mysql/mydb2 (If not using MySQL 8.0)
mv /var/lib/mysql/mydb1/mytb.ibd /var/lib/mysql/mydb2
```

If `mydb1` and `mydb2` are on the same disk volume, it would change the Linux i-nodes. Of course, the information_schema database gets updated in RAM. That's it. [Metadata locking would occur](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locking.html) during the move.

If the table files are symlinked, the symlinks are moved, nothing more.

**Now if you symlinked the database `mydb2` to be on a different disk volume, LOOK OUT !!! It has to initiate a table copy at the OS level.** This will not be the case for MySQL 8.0 since metadata is better managed than previous MySQL versions.

[See MySQL Docs on RENAME TABLE for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/symbolic-links-to-tables.html).

### SUGGESTION

Test renaming a 10G table in a Dev Server and see what occurs.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for that detailed response, I did check the MySQL docs but I wasn't sure what was happening at the filesystem level. In my case the databases should be on the same disk volume so it looks like it should just do the i-node change. Testing on a dev server is a good suggestion, will do that.

Comment: I tried the `RENAME` on MySQL 8.0 (on a small table).  No problem.

Comment: If a `TABLESPACE` or `DATA DIRECTORY` is specified, then a copy may be needed.

Comment: See also Akina's comment about Foreign Keys.